# Rename a directory during installation with the REN command

Tags: setup-project, nsis

I decided that the easiest way to rename the directory is through the REN command in windows with Exec. However, it just doesn't work. The program runs successfully, but doesn't do anything. Below is a basically what I'm trying to do.

```
OutFile "test.exe"
Section
Exec 'REN "C:\Rename me" "Done"'
SectionEnd
```

and by the way

```
REN "C:\Rename me" "Done"
```

works fine in cmd. I also tried RENAME with the same results.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ren is a internal command inside cmd.exe, you would have to execute `cmd.exe /c ren foo bar` but NSIS has a [Rename instruction](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.1.6), why not use that?

Comment: That works! Thank you. I got confused because the Rename Documentation seems to only be talking about files. But I should have tried that anyway...

Comment: "...and you can move a directory to somewhere else on the same drive"